# powershell's vertical space between consecutive commands

Tags: command-line, powershell, formatting

On windows 10, the output of any powershell command is displayed with additional vertical spaces. If you execute commands in sequence, on a 80x24 terminal session, you see more empty space than text. I looked around for powershell's default formatting, to change it, but did not find anything useful. Can you take me out of this misery please?

Example of code that shows the problem:

```
Get-NetAdapter | select Name,Status | format-table -autosize; Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -AllProperties -RegistryKeyword *Flo*rol,*SpeedDuplex,*JumboPacket,*Wake* | format-table Name,RegistryKeyword,DisplayValue,RegistryValue -autosize; Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -filter "IPEnabled='true'" | select Description,MACaddress,DHCPenabled,IPaddress,IPsubnet,DefaultIPGateway,DNSServerSearchorder,DNSdomain,Index
```

Comment: Can you provide some code that shows the issue? Because I have never run into that problem myself.

Comment: A screen shot of your issue would help us understand your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: I said *any command*. I see two empty lines before and after each output. If you run two commands in a raw, for example in a script, there is a gap of 4 empty lines between executions.

Comment: What, like `Write-Output "Test"`? I have never seen that happen. If we are talking about things like `Get-ChildItem` that offer a bit of *"graphical layout"*: why not use `$a = Get-ChildItem; $a | Format-Table -Property Name,LastWriteTime,Length -AutoSize`? Granted, that still only saves one line-break.

Comment: AutoSize takes care of the horizontal space only.

Comment: Would you be able to provide actual output and how it's looking for you?